# How to make links active with jquery in rails

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, navbar

I'm trying get some active links in my navbar and failing big time, what im doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-links text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <%= link_to "HOME", "#one", class: "navbar-links link-home" %>
  <%= link_to "FEATURES", "#features-container", class: "navbar-link link-home" %>
  <%= link_to "TEMPLATES", "#templates", class: "navbar-links link-home" %>
  <%= link_to "CONTACT", "#map", class: "navbar-links link-home" %>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.active-link {
  color: #C99D9A;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 80%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #C99D9A;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.navbar-links a').on('click', function(){
  $('this').removeClass('.active-link');
  $(this).addClass('.active-link');
});
```

Comment: What's the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: `$('this').removeClass('.active-link');` should be instead `$(this).removeClass('.active-link');`. You have single quotes around your this object.

Comment: ALSO: `$(this).removeClass('.active-link');` is wrong, in addClass/removeClass/toggleClass, you do not prefix your class with a fullstop('.'), `$(this).removeClass('active-link');` will work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a way the two **dots(.)** in **removeClass** and **addClass**. Following Jquery [document](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/): **`.removeClass( [className ] )`**

```
$('this').removeClass('active-link');
$(this).addClass('active-link');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.menu_ul li').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  //$(this).addClass('.active-link');
});
```

```css
.menu_ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-links text-center">
<ul class="menu_ul">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```